# Replacement for Project 2010 that lets multiple users edit at once?

Tags: ms-project, scheduling, resource-planning, ms-project-2010

We've been using Project 2010 and have a file saved to our network which we all enter data into and modify to track our projects. With licenses for Project 2010 no longer available, we were looking to migrate to a newer version.

With our current setup, only 1 person can edit the network file at once. We were hoping a newer version would let us have multiple people edit simultaneously, but that seems to be locked behind expensive monthly subscriptions.

Is there any way to get licenses for Project 2019 or 2021 and set it to allow multiple users edit access together, or is that completely locked behind a subscription?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Fred, The simple answer is "no". Project does not support co-authoring. And that makes sense because if more than one user has write access, there would be nothing to stop one user's input from conflicting with another user's input.

It doesn't matter is you have a subscription version of Project or a desktop version, the answer is the same.

What you can do is to create individual projects for each user and then insert those as subprojects into a master project for a total overview. However dynamically linked structures in Project are prone to corruption and if your "server" is SharePoint or OneDrive, linked structures are not supported.